# wp_list_categories: order by term order?

Tags: terms, categories, menu-order

I am currently using WordPress' `wp_list_categories` function in order to retrieve my terms from a specified taxonomy. I like this function for its ability to generate (hierarchical) HTML lists, that are equipped with proper class names, etc.

I have sorted my terms using the [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/) plugin, which works fine when I'm listing all terms the regular way (i.e. using get_terms).

However, whenever I try to list my terms using `wp_list_categories`, somehow it does not accept the *"orderby"* argument when using "term_order" (or "menu_order").

Could somebody point me in the right direction here?

I've provided my code below:

```
$categories = wp_list_categories([
     'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
     'title_li' => '',
     'orderby' => 'menu_order',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'echo' => 0,
     'current_category' => $current_term_id,
     'depth' => 0
]);
```

**Edit: I used `menu_order`, while I should have been using `term_order`. Still, I hope this serves somebody, some day :)**

Comment: Thanks, I think that plugin is quite useful;]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wp_list_categories()` function calls the `get_categories()` function, that's a wrapper for the `get_terms()` function, that creates an instance of the `WP_Term_Query` class. It doesn't look like it supports ordering by *term order*.

If the plugin uses the `term_order` column in the `wp_terms` table, then you can try to add a support for it's ordering, via the `get_terms_orderby` filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', function( $orderby, $qv, $taxonomy )
{
    // Only target the category taxonomy
    if( 'category' !== $taxonomy )
        return $orderby;

    // Support orderby term_order
    if( isset( $qv['orderby'] ) && 'term_order' === $qv['orderby'] )
        $orderby = 't.term_order';

    return $orderby;
}, 10, 3 );
```

where we only support this for the `category` taxonomy.

Another approach is to add the filter and remove it right after your `wp_list_categories()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your response @birgire, I will try this out tomorrow and get back to you... Have a nice evening.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Apparently I was using 'menu_order', rather than 'term_order'. Once I used the latter, it worked. And yes, the answer was obviously on my question. Sorry for wasting your time man! :P

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out. I understood from your question that you had tested both `term_order` and `menu_order` ;-) PS: It might be interesting to see how the plugin is storing the term order and how it sorts the terms. One can also wonder why `get_terms()/WP_Term_Query` doesn't support `term_order` ordering by default. @emozio

Comment: Yes, apparently I was running some inconsistent tests back then, which resulted in false postivies, **sort** to speak. ;-)

Comment: Happens to the best of us @emozio ,-)

Comment: This code will not work `if( 'category' !== $taxonomy )`, since $taxonomy is an array, you should test against $taxonomy[0], or each field `in_array( 'category', $taxonomy)`

Comment: thx welcome to edit as needed