# Change order of Wordpress tag cloud

Tags: taxonomy, tags, cloud

I have found the following function to change the behavour of the Wordpress tag cloud:

```
function widget_custom_tag_cloud($args) {

    $args['orderby'] = 'count';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'widget_custom_tag_cloud' );
```

However, I need to change the order from 'count' to 'menu_order'. Changing this line:

```
$args['orderby'] = 'count';
```

to

```
$args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
```

does NOT work.

Is it possible to do this or do I need to write a custom widget from scratch?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what to you mean by menu_order here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags (terms) do not have a `menu_order` (see the design of the table in the DB).

If you want to give terms a 'menu_order' you will need to create this yourself.

As long as your WP is >= 4.4.0, you can make use of the feature `term_meta`.

This is to terms what post meta is to posts.

You can create a 'menu_order' 'custom field' for terms and then you can set the menu order when creating/editing a term.

The relevant functions are:

```
add_term_meta();

update_term_meta();

get_term_meta();

delete_term_meta();
```

See here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta

And when query, your code won't do the trick for term meta. You need to write your own widget, that contains `get_terms()`. E.g.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'taxonomy_name', //can be array with multiple tax
    'meta_key' => 'menu_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$terms = get_terms($args);
```

To build the UI in admin panel & saving functions for adding/editing term's meta, the proccess is a little long for a SO/SE answer, I think.

If you Google 'wp term meta' you'll find out how to do it.

You will need 4 or 5 functions in all.

The hooks you will use are:

```
{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields // add the custom field to the 'new term' form

{$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields // add the custom field to the 'edit term' form

create_{$taxonomy} // for saving the term meta from the 'new term' form

edit_{$taxonomy} // for saving the term meta from the 'edit term' form

manage_edit-{$taxonomy}_columns // OPTIONAL adds a column, for the custom field, in the terms table for the taxonomy
```

Or, use a plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-meta/) (or copy the code in it).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `term_order`, then you could use the `tag_cloud_sort` filter to handle the sorting via PHP.

Here's an example, using `usort`:

```
add_filter( 'tag_cloud_sort', function( $tags, $args )
{
    // Nothing to do if no tags
    if( empty( $tags ) || ! is_array( $tags ) )
        return $tags;

    // Custom tag sort
    uasort( $tags, function( $a, $b )
    {
        if( $a->term_order === $b->term_order )
            return 0;

        return $a->term_order < $b->term_order ? - 1 : 1; // ASC
    } );

    return $tags;
}, 10, 2 );
```

that can be simplified in PHP 7 by using the [spaceship](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) comparison operator:

```
add_filter( 'tag_cloud_sort', function( $tags, $args )
{
    // Nothing to do if no tags
    if( empty( $tags ) || ! is_array( $tags ) )
        return $tags;

    // Custom tag sort
    usort( $tags, function( $a, $b )
    {
        return $a->term_order <=> $b->term_order; // ASC (swap $a and $b for DESC)
    } );

    return $tags;
}, 10, 2 );
```

The `wp_generate_tag_cloud()` function uses [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), but I don't think we need to preserve the index association here.

PS:

The `wp_cloud_tag()` function uses `get_terms()`, so an alternative could be to support `term_order` ordering in `get_terms()` via the `get_terms_orderby` filter. See e.g. a recent [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/243134/26350) here. I just tested the `term_order`  ordering by using the plugin mentioned by OP in the question that was answered there.