# show recently added tags to tag cloud

Tags: taxonomy, tags

Is there a way to show the most recently added tags to tag cloud?
Do I have to use the https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_tag_cloud/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with the default tag cloud.  The only options for ordering are "name" and "count".

You would need to add a new term to order by and probably use date.  See [this post's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247752/86845) for more details.